# XSLT Select lowest value of node based on id match

Tags: xml, xslt

XML Input:

```
<Root>


<output>
    <queries>
        <query name="Test">
            <parameters>
                <parameter>298674,298673,298675,298676</parameter>
            </parameters>
            <queryResults>
                <record id="1">
                    <column name="Order">272334</column>
                    <column name="Task">272093</column>
                    <column name="FirstAction">2709305</column>                     
                </record>
                <record id="2">
                    <column name="Order">272334</column>
                    <column name="Task">272093</column>
                    <column name="FirstAction">2709301</column>
                </record>
                <record id="3">
                    <column name="Order">272334</column>
                    <column name="Task">272093</column>
                    <column name="FirstAction">2709306</column>
                </record>
                <record id="4">
                    <column name="Order">268997</column>
                    <column name="Task">268756</column>
                    <column name="FirstAction">2709307</column>
                </record>
                <record id="5">
                    <column name="Order"/>
                    <column name="Task"/>
                    <column name="FirstAction">2709307</column>
                </record>
            </queryResults>
        </query>
    </queries>
</output>
</Root>
```

Desired Output:

```
<Tag1>
<Tag2>
    <parameters>
        <order id="272334"/>
        <order id="268997"/>
        <task id="272093">
            <grt>
                <action id="2709301"/>
            </grt>
        </task>
        <task id="268756">
            <grt>
                <action id="2709307"/>
            </grt>
        </task>
    </parameters>
</Tag2>
</Tag1>
```

I want for every column name = 'Order' that has the same ID to show in `<grt>` tag the lowest value of column name 'FirstAction'. If Column Name 'Order' does not repeat, then show in `<grt>` tag the value of 'FirstAction' from that current `<record>` tag. 
Basically, if the same order number repeats itself take the lowest first action number, if not then just take the value from the first action node.
I can't seem to make it work.

My XSL currently shows all the distinct values for order, without repeat, but don't know how to do for the FirstAction node.

My XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Tag1>
        <Tag2>
            <parameters>
                <xsl:for-each select="//record/column[@name='Order'][not(.=preceding::*)]">
                    <order>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                    </order>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="//record/column[@name='Task'][not(.=preceding::*)]">
                    <task>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
                        <grt>
                            <action>
                                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="current()/@column[@name='FirstAction']"/></xsl:attribute>
                            </action>
                        </grt>
                    </task>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </parameters>
        </Tag2>
    </Tag1>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: No :( only 1.0 sadly

Comment: Why is the last record, with no Order/task values. excluded from the result?

Comment: Because if I don't have any Order value i don't need to use any of those tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest you use the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to group your records - and do it only once.

Then use the same key to get the records in the current group, sort them by the `FirstAction` value, and get the first record in the sorted group:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="record-by-order" match="record" use="column[@name='Order']" />

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:variable name="unique-orders" select="//record[count(. | key('record-by-order', column[@name='Order'])[1]) = 1]"/>
    <Tag1>
        <Tag2>
            <parameters>
                <xsl:for-each select="$unique-orders">
                    <order id="{column[@name='Order']}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="$unique-orders">
                    <task id="{column[@name='Task']}">
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('record-by-order', column[@name='Order'])">
                            <xsl:sort select="column[@name='FirstAction']" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                <grt>
                                    <action id="{column[@name='FirstAction']}"/>
                                </grt>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </task>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </parameters>
        </Tag2>
    </Tag1>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tag1>
   <Tag2>
      <parameters>
         <order id="272334"/>
         <order id="268997"/>
         <order id=""/>
         <task id="272093">
            <grt>
               <action id="2709301"/>
            </grt>
         </task>
         <task id="268756">
            <grt>
               <action id="2709307"/>
            </grt>
         </task>
         <task id="">
            <grt>
               <action id="2709307"/>
            </grt>
         </task>
      </parameters>
   </Tag2>
</Tag1>
```

---

**Note**:

To exclude records with no `Order` value, try:

```
<xsl:variable name="unique-orders" select="//record[string(column[@name='Order'])][count(. | key('record-by-order', column[@name='Order'])[1]) = 1]"/>
```

Comment: YOU, sir, are a life saver! Thank you so much. I'll study this example and logic well so i'll know in the future. Ty